# How to split table columns inside the already splitted table?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design the following. I was almost in 3 years gap with coding.
I am confusing myself that how to split.
the code I tried is given below:

[image: My expected image here]

```html
<!-- grey color row code :   -->

<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-md-12 center-block text-center" style="background-color: #cccccc; color: black; border: solid; border-color: black; font-weight: bold">
    Row in grey color
  </div>
</div>
<!-- first table splitted as part A and part B: -->

<div class="row ">
  <div style="width: 50%; text-align: center; height: 30px; display: inline-block; border: solid; border-color: black; background: #80ffe5">
    PArt A
    <table>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_A1" checked>
        </td>
        <td>A1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_a2" checked>
        </td>
        <td>A2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_a3" checked>
        </td>
        <td>A3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_a4" checked>
        </td>
        <td>A4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_25" checked>
        </td>
        <td>A5
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="width: 50%; text-align: center; height: 30px; display: inline-block; border: solid; border-color: black; background: #80ffe5">
      <!--               Half PArt turqoise color header on left side only -->
      <table>
        <tr style="height: 30px">
          <td class="table">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_A1.1" checked>
          </td>
          <td>A1.1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 30px">
          <td class="table">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_a1.2" checked>
          </td>
          <td>A1.2
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 30px">
          <td class="table">
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_a1.3" checked>
          </td>
          <td>A1.3
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 50%; height: 30px; text-align: center; display: inline-block; border: solid; border-color: black; background: #80ffe5;">
    Part B
    <table>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b1" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B1
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b2" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B2
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b3" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B3
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b4" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b5" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B5
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b6" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B6
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b7" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B7
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="height: 30px">
        <td class="table">
          <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_b8" checked>
        </td>
        <td>B8
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 30px; display: inline-block; border: solid; border-color: black; background: #80ffe5">
    Escalation
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr style="height: 30px; widhth">
      <td class="table">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_A1.1" checked>
      </td>
      <td>A1.1
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_B1.1" checked>
      </td>
      <td>B1.1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 30px">
      <td class="table">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_a2.1" checked>
      </td>
      <td>A2.1
      </td>
      <td class="table">
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox_B1.2" checked>
      </td>
      <td>B1.2
      </td>
    </tr>
    <!-- @*3 more same <tr> here deleted due to code length*@   -->

  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please edit it to provide a [mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rqj08e7x/1/ here I tried with deleted few rows, the alignment is only problem. The CSS user as table is to border the table only.

Comment: if you want that blue cell going the full width, you cannot split your table into two columns (and 2 tables), you would need one table with 4 columns and then use colspan

Comment: @Pete I got one header in left side column alone in between checkbox, using colspan will fix that on too? here I mention that as Part C.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j4qpvmzk/ this is how you would do it with 1 table

Comment: @pete woww..thats what I am exactly looking for. Thank u so much, can u put ur answer separately below, so that I ll mark it as answer..

Comment: @pete only thing is there is a box around the checkbox column in my image.. to achieve this what we need to do ? writing any inline css will help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments: if you make it onto one table with four columns, you can use `colspan` to get what you want:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

th {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.checkbox {
  width: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">heading</th>
    <th colspan="2">heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">heading</th>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4">heading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
    <td class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: only thing is there is a box around the checkbox column in my image.. to achieve this what we need to do ? writing any inline css will help?

Comment: See edit - I added a border to the checkbox cell, and a border right to the last td and border bottom to the last row td

Comment: Actually, you can simplify the border by adding it to the table instead of the last children